# Bra-ket notation. What's the best way to do it?

Tags: physics, braket

Since the `{physics}` package is already out dated quite heavily (and has errors and isn't really compatible with `{siunitx}` anymore etc.), I wanted to ask, what is the best package for braket notation for quantum physics?

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions I have found (hope it helps other physic students :D):

1. `{braket}` package. This is quite acceptable for small stuff (package is pretty damn small if one looks at ctan), but also probably not the best, since the last update of it was in 2006 or so...
2. Defining commands via `{mathtools}` package (there is even an example in the documentation). Thus so far I use for braket commands (similar other math stuff):

> ```
> \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerp[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\delimsize\vert\mathopen{}#2}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\delimsize\vert\mathopen{}#2}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braketOP[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\ketbra[2]{\lvert}{\rvert}{#1\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle#2}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\outerp[2]{\lvert}{\rvert}{#1\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle#2}%
> \DeclarePairedDelimiterX\projector[1]{\lvert}{\rvert}{#1\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle#1}%
> ```

This leads to e.g.: [image: Example] Reproducable via the code:

```
\begin{align*}
    \ket{\psi}\\
    \bra{\psi}\\
    \ketbra{\psi}{\phi} = \outerp{\psi}{\phi}\\
    \projector{n}\\
    \innerp{\psi}{\phi} = \braket{\psi}{\phi}\\
    \braketOP{\psi}{U^{\dagger}HU}{\phi}\\
    \ket{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\ket{+}\pm\ket{-}\right) \\
    E = \frac{\braketOP{\psi}{H}{\psi}}{\innerp{\psi}{\psi}}\\
    A = \sum_i \projector{\psi_i} A \sum_j \projector{\psi_j} =\sum_{i,j} \ket{\psi_i} \braketOP{\psi_i}{A}{\psi_j} \bra{\psi_j} = \sum_{i,j} a_j \ket{\psi_i} \underbrace{\innerp{\psi_i}{\psi_j}}_{\delta_{ij}} \bra{\psi_j} = \sum_i a_i \projector{\psi_i}\\
    \bra{\psi_i} \underbrace{A\ket{\psi_j}}_{a_j}\\
    \braketOP{\psi}{\frac{A}{k}}{\phi}  = \braketOP*{\psi}{\frac{A}{k}}{\phi}\\
    \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\ket{0} + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{i\varphi}\ket{1} = \ket{\psi(\theta,\varphi)}
\end{align*}
```